# Getting null pointer exception when I run the following code

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dictionary

I have servlet in which it passes the map object from servlet to jsp and in jsp I will iterate over the map and display the values. But I getting null pointer exception when I pass the map object in setattribute method

```
try
    {

            Map<String,String> A=new HashMap<String,String>();
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connect=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("Connection");
    statement =(Statement)connect.createStatement();
    result=(ResultSet)statement.executeQuery("query");
    while(result.next())
    {
        A.put(result.getString("Hi"),result.getString("Hello"));
    }

    ServletContext context=getServletContext();

    request.setAttribute("A",A); // when I run i getting nullpointer exception here
    RequestDispatcher rd=context.getRequestDispatcher("/next.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

stacktrace:

> ```
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
> at search.classy.ClassDB.dbConnect(ClassDB.java:61)
> ```

Comment: If you can't solve it with exception stacktrace, how do you expect somebody else solve it *without* stacktrace? ;-)

Comment: @hyde added the stack trace

Comment: Well, obvious alternatives to check out: `A` is `NULL` (doesn't seem possible), `request` is `NULL` (impossible to estimate from code snippet), or `A` has `NULL` items (possible if `result.getString` returns `NULL` for "not found") but `NULL`s are not allowed in request attributes... You could start by ruling out these.

Comment: Are you sure with the line, where NPE is thrown? Try to add trace logs around your code to verify code flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSP tags:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
<c:forEach var="i" items="${A.keySet()}">
   Key <c:out value="${i}"/>
   Value <c:out value="${A.get(i)}"/>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sorry if there is a syntactical error, I do not have dev environment here to check syntax. But you should have a clue, how to solve your problem.

Comment: I responded to the first revision of his question, where was no stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

map i.e. A in your case should be put in response object.
It doesn't make sence to send something from server to client as a request instaed of response.

Comment: i changed my question please now solve the problem. I solved my previous problem now want to solve this

Comment: result=(ResultSet)statement.executeQuery("query"); // query should be some variable holding sql query [query = select Hi as Hi, Hello as hello from dual;]